# Android OpenCV Histogram is all 0s

Tags: android, opencv, histogram

I'm trying to generate a histogram based off a Mat that I have.  The Mat is of size 524x700 and contains numbers from 0-255.  Now when I try and run `Imgproc.calcHist` I am returned a Mat of size 1x25.  This is fine, but the the only data in the histogram is the very first value while the remaining values are 0.  Is there any reason for this?  My code is shown below: (*dst is of type `CvType.CV_32FC1`.

```
MatOfInt channels = new MatOfInt(0);
Mat hist = new Mat();
MatOfInt mHistSize = new MatOfInt(HISTOGRAMSIZE);
MatOfFloat mRanges = new MatOfFloat(0f, 255f);

Imgproc.calcHist(Arrays.asList(dst), channels, new Mat(), hist, mHistSize, mRanges);

for (int i = 0; i < hist.rows(); i++)
{
    double[] data2 = hist.get(i, 0);
    for (int k = 0; k < data2.length; k++)
    {
        String log = "hist_data:\t" + data2[k];
        Log.d(TAG, log);
    }
}
```

And the for loop outputs:

```
hist_data: 222768.0
hist_data: 0.0
hist_data: 0.0
hist_data: 0.0
.
.
.
```

And there are 24 0s that appear.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if there is some value way out of the 0-255 range, basically this means that most of your values are in the first bin and maybe one or two on the opposite side of the spectrum.

Try getting the minimum and maximum of that image to see if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your image range is (0, 1), and you compute the histogram for range (0, 255)